# Enviar valor de checkBox a firestore

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, checkbox, firestore

Me encuentro realizando una lista de chequeo mediante kotlin y necesito enviar varios valores de unos checkBox hacia Firestore, he intentado de diversas formas y buscado mucha info en sitios de programacion pero solo encuentro lo relacionado a Realtime Database, este es mi código actual con el cual logro enviar informacion pero en Firestore aparece como "true" o "False" en las respuestas, de antemano muchas gracias.

```
    **binding.btnsend6.setOnClickListener {
        val nombres = binding.Nombresss.selectedItem.toString()
        val nombres2 = binding.Nombresss2.selectedItem.toString()
        val nombres3 = binding.Nombresss3.selectedItem.toString()
        val nombres4 = binding.Nombresss4.selectedItem.toString()
        val fecha = binding.textViewcal6.text.toString()
        val sinona = binding.checkBox.isChecked.toString()
        val sinona2 = binding.checkBox2.isChecked.toString()
        val sinona3 = binding.checkBox3.isChecked.toString()
        val sinona4 = binding.checkBox4.isChecked.toString()
        val sinona5 = binding.checkBox5.isChecked.toString()
        val sinona6 = binding.checkBox6.isChecked.toString()
        val sinona7 = binding.checkBox7.isChecked.toString()
        saveFireStore(nombres,nombres2,nombres3,nombres4, fecha,  sinona, sinona2, sinona3, sinona4, sinona5, sinona6, sinona7)
    }**



   

}






private fun saveFireStore(
    nombres: String,
    nombres2: String,
    nombres3: String,
    nombres4: String, fecha: String, sinona: String, sinona2:String, sinona3:String,
    sinona4:String, sinona5:String, sinona6:String, sinona7:String) {

    **val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val user: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    user ["Nombre1"] = nombres
    user ["Nombre2"] = nombres2
    user ["Nombre3"] = nombres3
    user ["Nombre4"] = nombres4
    user ["Fecha"] = fecha
    user ["Peligros Trabajo en Altura1"] = sinona
    user ["Peligros Trabajo en Altura2"] = sinona2
    user ["Peligros Trabajo en Altura3"] = sinona3
    user ["Peligros Trabajo en Altura4"] = sinona4
    user ["Medidas de Control Trabajo en Altura1"] = sinona5
    user ["Medidas de Control Trabajo en Altura2"] = sinona6
    user ["Medidas de Control Trabajo en Altura3"] = sinona7**


    db.collection("ARD")
        .add(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@ArdActivity, "Guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@ArdActivity, "Falló", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
```

}

Comment: pues el valor de un checkbox siempre es `true` o `false`. Si lo que necesitas es el texto, usa `checkBox.text`

Comment: y para recibir solo lo seleccionado? añadí el text pero recibo en firestore toda la informacion de los checkbox sin importar si fue seleccionado o no

Comment: Deberías editar la pregunta, no queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer. Pero pareciera que simplemente necesitas un `if (checkBox.isChecked)`

Comment: En el fondo necesito que solo los checkbox seleccionados junto con sus textos se envien hacia firestore. Añadí el checkBox.text como me dijiste anteriormente pero con eso absolutamente todos los textos sin discriminar si estan o no seleccionados se envian a firestore.

Comment: Aún no queda claro si quieres omitir sólo el valor o el campo completo. Porque podrías enviar el campo con un valor `null` o una string vacía. En cualquier caso todo lo que necesitas es un `if`.  Por ejemplo `if (binding.checkBox.isChecked) user["Peligros Trabajo en Altura1"] = sinona`. Aunque es recomendable que los nombres de los campos no tengan espacios.